# How to exclude from Maven plugin in pom.xml file, a particular dependency?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have to exclude from Versions Maven Plugin command (use-latest-versions), a dependency that I don't want to automatically update.
Here is the doc:
https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html#excludes
This is how I have implemented the **excludes** optional parameter in the pom.xml file:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.1</version>
  <executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>use-latest-versions</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>["org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:jar:4.2.3"]</excludes>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Anyway during maven validate, the mongodb dependency is updated, ignoring the excludes parameters. Where is the mistake?

**EDIT:**
Now it works. Below the correct configuration:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.1</version>
  <executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>use-latest-versions</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:jar:4.2.3</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Comment: Usually you could give`<excludes><exclude>...</exclude></excludes>`...

Comment: Thank you, the documentation of the plugin is poor, but this is the correct way

Comment: Than I would suggest to make JIRA issue to improve the documentation... may be you could offer a pull request...